# SyntaxHighlighter Evolved not showing vertical and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: plugin-syntaxhighlighter

When I use [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter)
I cannot see the horizontal and vertical code scroll bars (I use Google Chrome browser).

Do you know how to fix this?

Any other code snippets to suggest for WordPress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on my site and it worked fine. Try adding this to your css file, or in the syntax highlighter advanced settings where it says additional classes:

```
.syntaxhighlighter td {
overflow-x:scroll !important;
}
```